# Teapot Riddle: my first is nice and pleasant and lovely, my second really quite

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Same rules as before:
I have **one** word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my clues.

First clue:

> My first teapot is nice and pleasant and lovely.
>   My second teapot really quite.

Second clue:

> My first teapot is an adjective.
>   My second teapot is an adverb.

Third clue:

> My first Teapot makes a word more beautiful.
>   My second Teapot makes a word stronger.

Comment: If I go back and read all the earlier ones, will it become apparent why _teapots_?

Comment: i really dont know why its called 'teapots'. But in the first Riddle we discussed a bit aout this type of riddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you:

> Pretty

First:

> A pretty object is nice and pleasant and lovely, and pretty good is really quite good.

Second:

> Pretty is an adjective that describes someone as good looking, Pretty is an adverb that describes a verb in a positive light.

Third:

> A pretty person is a more beautiful person, a pretty good thing is a very good thing, so it makes the "good" into a stronger "good"

Comment: youre right ... again

Comment: Sorry! I managed to get it with only the first hint this time, but I can edit in the explanations of the other hints if you like?

Comment: Yes, why not. In which order do you want the hints?