# Teapot Riddle no.6

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Here's riddle numero 6:
Same rules as always:
I have **one** word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints

*yayyy*

First Hint

> My first teapot is designed pragmaticly
>  My second teapot is designed for glamour

Second Hint

> My first teapot is partly of metal
>  My second teapot is fully made of metal

Third Hint

> My first teapot is commonly known for real pain
>  My second teapot too, loooool

Final Hint

> My first teapot has bindings on its sides
>  My secongs teapot is a symbol for binding

Good luck and have much fun :)

for more fun checkout my [riddle no.5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72159/teapot-riddle-no-5)

Comment: You're in luck, I have no idea about this one :P

Comment: No way :O , I reached my lifegoal i set two hours earlier :P

Comment: i missed 'to ring (a bell)', it would also be a possible teapot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is

> a ring  (boxing and wedding)

because

> boxing ring is pragmatic arena, wedding ring is glamorous
>  boxing ring has some metal, wedding ring is all metal
>  boxing ring causes pain, so does wedding ring (sometimes :) )
>  boxing ring has bindings on the sides, wedding ring binds two together

Comment: I think this is it!  However, ROT13(Znlor vg'f "ratntrzrag" vafgrnq bs "jrqqvat" - gung qvnzbaq uhegf gb trg uvg jvgu)

Comment: you got it again (last time was kind of a draw) , Congrats @SteveV

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to throw this out there, it works for most of the clues.  Is this teapot:

> Spine - Vertebral column/spine of a book

First Hint:

> The back is designed to support the rest of the body, so "pragmaticly"
> Book spines can have intricate designs

Second Hint:

> As someone who has herniated a disc, metal fusion is a thing
> The round circles used in notebooks are metal

Third Hint:

> Back pain is a terrible thing
> Not sure, maybe the metal spines can pinch?  Can be used to hit?

Final Hint:

> I'm thinking however the vertebrae connect to other parts of the body (I'm no doctor, bear with me lol)
> It binds the pages together in the (note)book

Comment: thats not the word. but cool to have you onboard again

Comment: Thanks! I really enjoy these teapots (even if my thinking is usually wrong)

Comment: I love you for your alternative solutions

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think I’m right but could this be

> CUFFS?

My first teapot is designed pragmatically

> Cuffs as in handcuffs? They’re pragmatic.

My second teapot is designed for glamour

> Cuffs as in those on suit sleeves.

Second Hint
My first teapot is partly of metal

> The cuff links on the cuffs are.

My second teapot is fully made of metal

> Handcuffs are fully metal.

Third Hint
My first teapot is known for real pain

> Being in a suit is painful?

My second teapot too, loooool

> So is being in handcuffs.

Final Hint
My first teapot has bindings on its sides

> Cuff links on sides.

My secongs teapot is a binding

> Handcuffs are bindings.

Comment: thats not the word. but nice try