# Teapot Riddle no.7

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

everyone doing rhymes here
Teapot Riddle no.7
eeeeeh ...
get me some beer

Rules:
I have **one** word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

- First Hint:
  My first teapot exists in all 3 Dimensions.
  My second teapot needs just 2 Dimensions to exist, but can contain more.
- Second Hint:
  My first teapot is a place for consuming.
  My second teapot is a place for storaging.
- Third Hint:
  My first teapot has legs.
  My second teapot has a head.
- Final Hint:
  My first teapot is made of wood, or glass or even stone.
  My second teapot is made of lines.

Good luck and have fun
[more fun](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72177/teapot-riddle-no-6)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is your teapot a

> TABLE?

My first teapot exist in all 3 Dimensions

> As in a dinner table.

My second teapot needs just 2 Dimension to exist, but can contain more

> As in a data table.

Second Hint
My first teapot is a place for consuming

> You eat at the dinner table.

My second teapot is a place for storaging

> You store data in a data table.

Third Hint
My first teapot has legs

> Dinner tables have legs.

My second teapot has a head

> Data tables have headers.

Final Hint
My first teapot is made of wood, or glass or even stone

> Dinner tables can be made of wood, glass, or stone.

My second teapot is made of lines

> Data tables are made of lines.

Comment: you're right.  when did you figure it out?

Comment: The second hint helped a lot, @Jannis; the final hint confirmed it for me I think!