# Teapot Riddle no.8

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot riddle no.8: *"rules as every year, James"*:
I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

- First Hint:
  My first teapot seems to be made of everything
  My second teapot can be made of standing
- Second Hint:
  My first teapot is a flavor of life
  My second teapot is a problem of life
- Third Hint:
  My first teapot is made by your Grandma
  My second teapot is made by every other Person on the street
- Final Hint:
  Have you tried Pancakes with it?
  Have you tried riding instead of it?

Good luck, have fun
more fun: [last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72271/teapot-riddle-no-7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it

> Jam (the first one is the food (Jam/Jelly) and the second is the traffic jam

First Hint

> Vareity of Jams (Mixed fruit, orange, strawberries, etc.)
>  Not sure though

Second Hint

> My first teapot is a flavor of life
>  -  Jam is the sweet and the most delicious flavor (avoiding the sugar-free  references here) :D
> My second teapot is a problem of life
>  - Traffic jams are a real problem almost everywhere

Third Hint

> My first teapot is made by your Grandma
>  My second teapot is made by every other Person on the street

Final Hint

> Have you tried Pancakes with it?
>  Have you tried riding instead of it?

Comment: youre right  :)  how did you get to your conclusion?

Comment: first I thought of honey.. but jam was an appropriate fit..