# Teapot Riddle no.9

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Rules for Teapot Riddle no.9:

I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

- First Hint:
  My first teapot can be produced easily, but evaluated hardly
  My second teapot can be produced hardly, but evaluated easily
- Second Hint:
  My first teapot is historically interesting
  My second teapot is also historically interesting, but of minor value
- Third Hint:
  My first teapot is various
  My second teapot is really various, like ... WOW*
- Final Hint:
  My first teapot is touchable
  My second teapot is not touchable but beatable

Good luck and have fun :)
[Last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72303/teapot-riddle-no-8)

Comment: WOW* means amongst other things [this](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/man-worlds-longest-fingernails-finally-gets-manicure-180969633/)

Comment: A riddle here should be solvable even *without* using any spoilertagged material. So, you should either turn the spoilertags into normal text or add more normal text at the top.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the word is

> RECORD.

First meaning is

> record as in recorded document.

second meaning is

> record as in [extreme performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_record).

*My first teapot can be produced easily, but evaluated hardly*
*My second teapot can be produced hardly, but evaluated easily*

> It's easy to record something, but then a list of records can be hard to evaluate. It's hard to make a new world record, but easy to evaluate because it just needs to be better than the last one.

*My first teapot is historical interesting*
*My second teapot is also historical interesting, but of minor value*

> A written record of some fact may be very historically interesting. A new world record is interesting only up until it's beaten.

*My first teapot is various*
*My second teapot is really various, like ... WOW**

> Information can be recorded in various ways. World records also vary a lot, and can be amazing.

*My first teapot is touchable*
*My second teapot is not touchable but beatable*

> You can touch a record on a piece of paper, and you can beat a world record.