# Teapot Riddle no.10

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Teapot Riddle no.10
*celebrates inside*
Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

*somebody told me i should make my hints not hidden*
First Hint

> My first teapot is godlike
>   My second teapot is quite common

Second Hint

> My first teapot helps making food
>   My second teapot helps preparing food

Third Hint

> My first teapot causes mass panics
>   My sceond teapot causes mass panics only in PUBG :D

Final Hint

> My first teapot is the christian devil
>   My second teapot is just hot.

Good luck and have fun
[last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72372/teapot-riddle-no-9)

Comment: Can I suggest adding the knowledge tag (for the third hint)?

Comment: Can the second teapot's third hint be extended to other games, or does it apply literally only to PUBG?

Comment: not really, the line with pubg was a joke, the teapot exists there but dont causes mass panics, actually it isnt really seen there oftenly. try focusing on the first hint. and the second teapot is only applied to pubg (and tangled)

Comment: I have made a [fan made teapot riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72423/teapot-riddle-no-11-fan-made). Are you okay with this?

Comment: @user477343 definetly +1 from me. go on and make more riddles, no need to ask me about that :), i also love figuring teapot riddles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the word is

> PAN

Meanings:

> Pan is the name of a god, sometimes associated with Satan.
>  Pan, as in a frying pan.

Clues:

My first teapot is godlike. My second teapot is quite common

> Pan is a god. Pans are common.

My first teapot helps making food. My second teapot helps preparing food.

> As a god, Pan is connected with wilderness, shepherds, fields, fertility and Spring, therefore, he helps with the creation of food. Pans are used to prepare food.

My first teapot causes mass panics. My sceond teapot causes mass panics only in PUBG :D

> [The word panic "derives from antiquity and is a tribute to the ancient god, Pan"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panic#Etymology). Pans appear in PUBG as melee weapons.

My first teapot is the christian devil. My second teapot is just hot.

> Pan is sometimes associated with Satan because of how it looks. Pans are hot when used to cook.

Comment: you were first, but i'll guess Jim W and El-Guest are on 1st place too since their answers were just seconds too late

Comment: Yeah, it was close. This was a cool challenge. It was the first time I've participated guessing something in this site (in fact, I didn't even know how to hide my answer haha).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Done!

Comment: And upvoted! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Is this

> Pan?

My first teapot is godlike

> As in the Greek god Pan?

My second teapot is quite common

> As in a frying pan?

Second Hint
My first teapot helps making food

> He was the god of the wild, of shepherds and sheep — sheep can be food?

My second teapot helps preparing food

> You cook food in a frying pan.

Third Hint
My first teapot causes mass panics

> The word PANIC is derived from Pan’s name.

My sceond teapot causes mass panics only in PUBG :D

> The frying pan weapon in PUBG?

Final Hint
My first teapot is the christian devil

> Pan has goat like features, as does Satan.

My second teapot is just hot.

> Frying pans are hot.

Answer (score 6):

Im going to guess the teapot is

> pan

first hint:

> pan is both a god and a normal house hold item

second hint:

> this one might be a stretch but obviously a pan is useful in cooking and the god Pan has been known to prepare a meal from time to time

third hint:

> the origin of the word panic is from pan causing people to flee in terror, the pan is also a notorious weapon in pubg (plus the tangled reference in the comments)

final hint:

> AGH I didnt finish writing my answer to this before someone else answered, curse my slow fingers

Comment: Same happened to me just couldn't type fast enough

Comment: sheeps are also food. @Jim W but you're right food in that context isnt really that appropriate, but ***is also the god of nature and that implies wild berries, look up [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_(god)), ***is a really widespread god

Comment: @Jannis thanks, if I wasn't trying to race to be first I would have read more up about Pan, the god, and had a better justification for my answers.  The PUBG/ Tangled comment sold it for me and I just knew I had to get as much down as I could.  Love the teapot puzzles too keep em up!

Comment: I love it, that you love my riddles, I dont want to make actual races,but  to whom should i give the 'right answer' tag, else than the first?

Answer (score 4):

Is your teapot

> Pan

For the first hint:

> Pan is a god in Greek mythology, and also a common cooking item

Second Hint:

> Pan is a god of nature and shepherds so helps with making food, the tool pan is used to cook food

Third Hint:

> The word panic came from the God's name, a Pan is also a weapon in PUBG

Final Hint:

> This could be referring to how Pan is another religion's god which is against the bible or the fact that the god Pan is also a symbol of sex, a pan is used at high temperatures usually

Comment: second place but cool having you here