# Teapot Riddle no.12

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I got top 5 last week with only asking the Teapot Riddles and your upvotes. I find that quite nice <3. Anyway here's
**Teapot Riddle no.12**
*explosions*

Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

First Hint:

> My first teapot is a non-spoken language
>   My second teapot is a non-noticeable language

Second Hint:

> My first teapot is hurting
>   My second teapot hurts only by minimal links

Third Hint:

> My first teapot draws attention
>   Years ago my second teapot has drawn attention

Final Hint (makes it a lot easier | you can try without using):

> My first teapot is a sign of (no or sometimes a) friendship
>  My second teapot is a sign of wealth

Good luck and have fun

I want to thank [user477343](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42452/user477343) for the [cool riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72423/teapot-riddle-no-11-fan-made)
as always: [my last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72387/teapot-riddle-no-10)

Comment: Thank you for the mention! I have reached my daily voting limit and have to wait $13$ hours before I am able to upvote again (DVL13) so Imma favourite it $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: after 200 views without the answer: links are buttons , And years ago is probably 200- 500 years. non-noticeable means nobody really cares

Comment: It sems to me my word is so not-noticeable, that most Persons don't even come to think about it. Only El-Guest did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the teapot a

> cuff

My first teapot is a non-spoken language
My second teapot is a non-noticeable language

> When you cuff someone, that is a non-verbal statement.  Cuffs on your sleeves are not as noticeable as they once were

My first teapot is hurting
My second teapot hurts only by minimal links

> When you cuff someone, it might hurt.  Cuffs with out enough links can cause problems

My first teapot draws attention
Years ago my second teapot has drawn attention

> Cuffing someone will get their attention.  Cuffs on sleeves used to be attention getters.

Final hint

> You can cuff someone in a friendly or non-friendly manner, wearing cuff links used to be a sign of wealth.

Comment: links that are too small are way to hard to button up, i hurted myself often times....         when did you get to your answer?

Comment: After you said links are buttons, ironically, I eventually thought of sleeves and cuffs and links!

Comment: I didn't know my riddle was so hard to figure: EL-Guest has thought of this teapot in riddle no 6 or so

Answer (score 5):

Are you..

> gesture?

My first teapot is non-spoken language
My second teapot is non-noticeable language

> first: body movement, second: monetary gift, not noticeable physically

My first teapot is hurting
My second teapot hurts only by minimal links

> first: gesturing too much will end in sore muscles, which hurts! second: hurts only your wallet, not your body.

My first teapot draws attention
Years ago my second teapot has drawn attention

> first: gesturing draws attention to you, second: monetary gifts have become so usual, such a gesture is not likely to draw public attention anymore (uhhhhhhmm... yeeeeahhhh...)

final hint:

> My first teapot is a sign of friendship
> My second teapot is a sign of wealth
> ----
> first: using your hands when you speak is maybe more agreeable/*friendly* to listen to? second: gifting money sure shows your wealth

additional note:

> I am not sure if in English, gesture can mean a (monetary) gift too. If not, please let me know and I'll remove my answer again. I'm okay with posting a wrong answer (I know it is) but not one that does make no sense ;)

Comment: i think your answer makes sense!  The meaning is there in English too.

Comment: It's wrong but pls dont delete your answer: Anybody who guesses same as you, can correct themselves still, if you let this post here. Nice try i hope you guess on:)  and: i wouldn't take teapots which meanings are close together

Comment: As i said, I wouldn't delete it just because it's wrong. Since apparently the meaning is there too in English, this answer stays forever :)

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this one for a while. Is it

> Tribute?

It has 2 meanings that somewhat match the hints. First is

> A non-spoken gesture of appreciation (why does it hurt though?..)

And the second is

> payment from one nation to another, usually for protection

Well, at least I tried :)

Comment: Welcome to puzzling se. it's not ... sorry. Cool that you have tried :) your teapot is also quite nice, maybe i'm making a riddle out of it. or you do by yourself. tip: last hint keep on focusing on fri******* Have a nice day or even have the right idea to solve it :D

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Answer:

Could the teapot be

> **LEAVES**?

`My first teapot is non-spoken language`

> To **leave** a place is body language (though it can also be spoken with the word "goodbye").

`My second teapot is non-noticeable language`

> Stumped on this.

`My first teapot is hurting`

> If you **leave** a relationship, the consequences can be hurtful.

`My second teapot hurts only by minimal links`

> Ripping up **leaves** can "hurt" them, but to a minimal extent, of course.

`My first teapot draws attention`

> **Leaving** a place can draw attention, depending on what place/event you leave (e.g. your friend's birthday party), or how you have left (e.g. expelled from school).

`Years ago my second teapot has drawn attention`

> Stumped on this one, too.

I haven't looked at the final hint... should I?

---

<sub><sup>Pup kag zafuoq yk "efgybqp" bgz? Me uz, "fdqq efgyb"?</sup></sub>

Comment: It's not leave, try with the last Hint :) you tried and that's cool

Comment: @Jannis Hah, I just realised that "left" and "right" are both teapot words (if that's what you call 'em) :D

Comment: more or less,: leave (go) and leaves (forest), left (went) and left (side)  and right(correct) and right(side) are all teapots. They're not perfectly for my riddles, since hard to explain sides, but useable

Comment: rot14? really? :D

Comment: @Cashbee glad you noticed :P

Answer (score 0):

Is the teapot a

> Status?

Teapot#1

> Status on the social networking platforms

Teapot#2

> A persons position in the society

**First Hint:**

My first teapot is a non-spoken language

> Sometimes a status tells more than what is posted

My second teapot is a non-noticeable language

> A person's status is (most of the times) non-noticeable

**Second Hint:**

My first teapot is hurting

> A negative/offensive status often hurts

My second teapot hurts only by minimal links

> Not really sure

**Third Hint:**

My first teapot draws attention

> Any status on any Social Networking platform draws attention

Years ago my second teapot has drawn attention

> Maybe something to do with the status of the Kings or the Highnesses