# Teapot riddle no.13 (fan made)

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

**Teapot Riddle no.13 (fan made).** 
*Direction*.

> > **Rules:**
>
> *I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
>
> Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...).
>
> You try to figure out the word with my Hints.*

- **First Hint:**

  > My first teapot ends, and my second will show. 
  >  Of them, one extends, with the other narrow.
- **Second Hint:**

  > My first teapot tips without movements or spills. 
  >  My second *has* tips using what mainly feels.
- **Third Hint:**

  > My first teapot's thin, maybe sharp at the head. 
  >  My second might sin if the middle is lead.
- **Final Hint (to make it easy):**

  > My third teapot's placed between units and so, 
  >  Specifically based on its own ratio.

Good luck and have fun!
[Last teapot riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72439/teapot-riddle-no-12). Big thanks to @[Jannis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52327/jannis) for making them!

Comment: Love ur teapot riddles mate. They're just amazing :D

Comment: @KevinL thank you! Your riddles are very good too, don't forget! Especially your Riley Rebuses :D

Comment: yeah, haven't made a riley rebus in a while. Will probably make one quite soon (I have to focus on annoying exams, lol) :D

Comment: @KevinL Hah, I don't have exams yet, but I still have to pause my progress on riddles because of school, so I understand your point. Sorry for this delayed reply. My computer died and I couldn't find my charger. I went to sleep and just found it this morning, hahah :P

Comment: Yeah, no problem mate :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I now think it is:

> POINT

The first teapot being:

> A sharp tip

And the second being:

> What you do with your finger

My first teapot ends, and my second will show.

> When something narrows to a point, it ends. But pointing with a finger *shows* where something is.

Of them, one extends, with the other narrow.

> You extend your finger to point, whereas the point of something is the narrow end.

My first teapot tips without movements or spills.
My second has tips using what mainly feels.

> When something narrows to a point it has a tip. Your fingers, which point (and also feel), have tips.

My first teapot's thin, maybe sharp at the head.
My second might sin if the middle is lead.

> The point of something is a sharp end. And if you "point" with your middle finger is a little bit rude, and the meaning could be considered a "sin" by some.

My third teapot's placed between units and so,
Specifically based on its own ratio.

> A third definition of "point" is a relative measure of the size of a font.

Comment: The meaning behind it would definitely be considered a "sin" (at least in some religions)!

Comment: That is not the answer, but can pass an alternative! You are searching in the right area, and funnily enough, some of your explanations for your answer are the actual explanations for the *intended* answer. You are so close, but I might award you a $50$ rep bounty because of this beautiful answer :D

Comment: @Greg e.g. (ROT13) anvyvat Puevfg ba gur pebff, but that is not the intended explanation (assuming that is what you are referring to) :P

Comment: In fact... the intended answer is in your answer, but is not what you answered... :P

Comment: @user477343 I was thinking ROT13(Gur zvqqyr svatre, zrnavat "s*px lbh," jbhyq or phefvat, juvpu vf n "fva")

Comment: @Greg Well, that is the correct reasoning, then! But... relate that to the title as opposed to a Rot13(anvy) :D

Comment: @user477343 I'm scared of editing my question and getting further away from the correct answer. I'm thinking: Vg pbhyq or "svatre", ohg V unir ab vqrn juvpu nygreangvir zrnavat pbhyq or grncbg ahzore 1. Sbe gur guveq zrnavat va lbhe ynfg uvag juvpu V cerivbhfyl vtaberq vg pbhyq gura or "n svatre fcnpr"

Comment: No, it is not that. What is the middle finger doing, as you describe? What point am I trying to make? (Read this comment carefully!)

Comment: @user477343 ok how about now?

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct! (Sorry for this delayed reply. My computer died and I had to go to bed after that. I found the charger this morning, so I can be on, now.) However, your third explanation is incorrect, but still fits. The intended one  referred to a Rot13(qrpvzny cbvag), but other than that, you got it! Well done! Even though you completely edited your answer, I will still give you a $50$ rep bounty for that last original thought! Now, when would you like the tick? :D

Comment: Eh well, Imma tick you now. Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 3):

Are you a..

> Slash?

My first teapot ends, and my second will show.
Of them, one extends, with the other narrow.

> to slash out extends your arm, the character slash (`/`) is narrow

My first teapot tips without movements or spills.
My second has tips using what mainly feels.

> `/` is tipped but doesn't spill

My first teapot's thin, maybe sharp at the head.
My second might sin if the middle is lead.

> `/` is thin and sharp at the end

Final Hint:

> My third teapot's placed between units and so,
> Specifically based on its own ratio.
> -----
> Oh, the `/` is the third teapot.. (for example "km/h" - the slash stands between units and makes a ratio out of them) hm I guess I mixed them up anyway.. ups. So a third(second maybe?) teapot could be the famous guitarist Slash?

Additional notes:

> this answer has too many unanswerable clues, but yet there are many where they hit the *nail* (hehe) in the head, so I had to post.

Comment: It is not a Rot13(fynfu), but @Astralbee 's original answer was a very great alternative. I never knew there was a famous guitarist called that, hahah! Sorry for this delayed reply. I had to go to sleep because it was late, and my computer died before I did. (I just found the charger this morning, actually.) But anyway, 'twas a great attempt, though, and very good answer! :D

Comment: @user477343 don't worry I was not actively waiting for a reply ;) There is a whole south park episode about that guitarist, it's super funny (S15E05). I think my answer fits the final hint way better than the correct answer. Not the rest though :/

Comment: Well, regarding that final hint, I disagree, but that doesn't mean this is a great answer. I upvoted before, and I wanna see that episode (I used to watch South Park. Has the seasons ended now, by the way?)

Comment: Hehe no they are still going.

Comment: And I posted another riddle. You have only posted three riddles. Do you write riddles often?

Comment: @user477343 I was just reading it. And no not very often, only since I frequent this stack and only on sudden inspirations. I want to have more of those though :)

Comment: Well, I don't know if you are the right person to ask, but do you think there is anything I could improve on my riddle you just read? I am always looking for improvement, so any advice would likely help :)

Comment: sure, lets do that in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)

Answer (score 2):

**Partial**

Is it just?:

> Finger (based on Astralbee's answer and comments).  Not sure about the first teapot, but the second would be the fingers on your hand.

Comment: No, that is not it. I understand where you are coming from though :)

Comment: I didn't think so, thought I'd try anyway :-)

Comment: 'Tis a good guess, nevertheless! :D

Answer (score 2):

I am going to guess, it is a

> Line

Explanation:

> not much to explain here, its a wild guess based on few lines
> **My first teapot ends**
> **My first teapot tips without movements or spills**
> **My first teapot's thin, maybe sharp at the head.** 
>  and **My third teapot's placed between units and so**

Comment: I appreciate your wild guess, but that is unfortunately not the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is already answered but:
i have **the** solution :D
*maybe not the right solution but **the** solution*

> Its a gnome:
>  means: dwarflike troll or epigram/aphorism
>  since google translator exist

First Hint:
My first teapot ends, and my second will show.
Of them, one extends, with the other narrow.

> The gnomes life or height ends, and they are pretty small(narrow)
>  the aphorism shows a truth, extends our knowledge

Second Hint:
My first teapot tips without movements or spills.
My second has tips using what mainly feels.

> I'd guess gnomes can't hold balance when standing still/frozen
>  Aphorismsn can have tips, which can be useful in life

Third Hint:
My first teapot's thin, maybe sharp at the head.
My second might sin if the middle is lead.

> Gnomes are small and maybe they have stolen dwarfs hat so they have gotten sharp
>  If one of nazi leaders have written in an aphorism it could contain sins...

Final Hint (to make it easy):

> My third teapot's placed between units and so,
>  Specifically based on its own ratio.
>  maybe a type of gnome can change forms (ratio height-width-lenght) to fit and hid everywhere... Maybe even in your open mouth xD

Have a funny day :D

Comment: Hahah, I love this! I have to wait $14$ hours before I upvote, as I have reached my daily voting limit (DVL14), but apart from that, great answer! :D